# BunifuMaterialTextbox isPassword is not working

Tags: vb.net-2010

i'm trying to create a login form using the textbox of bunifu but when i do set the properties: isPassword to true it seems not working. how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

same with me, the isPassword method not working.
You can try make the textbox isPassword every value change on the textbox using this code

```
 private void txtMyTextBox_OnValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtMyTextBox.isPassword = true;
        }
```